Looking for a way to build a windows / linux / wasm distributed app
I have a few bits of hardware that I can access: some windows/linux computers where I can copy to & run binaries (not all of them are on the same network, but luckily at least one of them has a public ip), and some others where I cannot run binaries but where I can use a browser to launch a page with a webasm app. I need to build a computationally (but not memory or io) intensive distributed app for them. What seems to be the easiest option? Ideally the difference between windows / linux / webasm should be abstracted away and the communication between the nodes should be the handled as seamlessly as possible, so I should only care about the logic of the app itself. Integer number crunching performance is a must.
